# Enumeration as Argument for a function called in a block

Tags: ios, swift

i wrote a function, that takes an enumeration value as argument. I don't get any errors for the function prototype, but as soon as i try to call the function an an block, ill get an error saying "Use of unresolved identifier":

```
@IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let actionMenu = UIAlertController(title: "Take a Photo or choose an  
    existing one", message: nil, preferredStyle:    
    UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let takePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "take Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        println("take Photo")
    })
    let choosePhotoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "choose an existing Photo", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        println("choose Photo")
        //getting error right here    
        self.displayPickerController(UIImagerPickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
    })

    actionMenu.addAction(takePhotoAction)
    actionMenu.addAction(choosePhotoAction)

    presentViewController(actionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


// MARK: - Helper Methods

func displayPickerController(withSource: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType){
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = withSource
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `self.displayPickerController(UIImagerPickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)`. You typed `UIImager` instead of `UIImage` when naming the enum.